# git выгрузить commit в мастер

Tags: git

работаю с веткой master по средствам мерджа с моей рабочей веткой, возникла необходимость откатить свой файл в мастере на ранний коммит. не понятно как это сделать т.к. если я делаю git checkout <номер коммита>, затем git add, commit, push он не видит не каких изменений, при мердже с мастером

Comment: попробуйте git reset для файла по sha коммита и дальше пушьте, вот например - https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы когда делаете git checkout <номер коммита> ваш указатель HEAD находится в состоянии detached. То есть все изменения которые вы сделаете при таком состоянии указателя HEAD не применятся. Вам нужно воспользоваться командой reset чтобы откатиться на более ранний commit. при этом используя нужный вам режим (soft mixed hard)

Comment: режим (soft mixed hard) а в чем отличия?

Comment: Лучше почитайте документацию, Чтобы не ошибиться. hard - удалит изменения после выбранного коммита, mixed - (режим по умолчанию) перенесет все изменения в неотслеживаемую зону.  И soft - переместит изменения в отслеживаемую зону. То есть делайте аккуратней, так как при использовании hard - вы можете утратить данные после коммита, на который вы откатываетесь.

Comment: Когда делаю reset у меня откатывается и другие файлы участников возможно ли откатить только один файл?

Comment: Да, в таком случае вам нужна команда         git checkout <хэш коммита> -- file1       после этой команды file1 вернется к своему состоянию в том коммите, и в репозитории перейдет в отслеживаемую зону.